# opening a file with filename generated

Tags: python

```
section = int(1)
configuration_file = "Section_" + str(section) +"_configurations"
print configuration_file
conf_file = open(configuration_file + '.txt','r')
```

my file is not opening even though correct file name is generated and the file exists

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: Is the file in your current working directory?

Answer (score 1):

personally, I would replace the last line by:

```
with open(configuration_file+'.txt','r') as f:
    line=f.readline()
    print(line)
    ...
```

this way you don't have to close the file.

I would also add a check before the open:

```
import os, sys
if not os.path.isfile(configuration_file+'.txt'):
    print('error: file not found')
    sys.exit(-1)
```